# Validating phone numbers. Null is not an object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm doing a challenge on Freecodecamp. I'm having a problem that seems to make no sense to me.

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {

  // if string contains a letter then return false //
  var exc = /[a-z\?/]/;

  // check str to see if it has anything from the //
  // regex and then make it into a string. //
  var excJoin = str.match(exc).join('');

  // if theres something in the //
  // variable(something was found with regex) //
  // then return false //

  if(excJoin.length > 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // else return true //
  if(excJoin === null){return true;}
}


telephoneCheck("2(757)622-7382");
```

Returning `false` is fine, however when I just want to say `else {return true;}` it tells me null is not an object. What's the problem?

[http://freecodecamp.com/challenges/validate-us-telephone-numbers](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/validate-us-telephone-numbers#?solution=%0Afunction%20telephoneCheck(str)%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20if%20string%20contains%20a%20letter%20then%20return%20false%20%2F%2F%0A%20%20var%20exc%20%3D%20%2F%5Ba-z%5C%3F%2F%5D%2F%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20check%20str%20to%20see%20if%20it%20has%20anything%20from%20the%20%2F%2F%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20regex%20and%20then%20make%20it%20into%20a%20string.%20%2F%2F%0A%20%20var%20excJoin%20%3D%20str.match(exc).join('')%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20if%20theres%20something%20in%20the%20%2F%2F%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20variable(something%20was%20found%20with%20regex)%20%2F%2F%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20then%20return%20false%20%2F%2F%0A%20%20%0A%20%20if(excJoin.length%20%3E%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20else%20return%20true%20%2F%2F%0A%20%20if(excJoin%20%3D%3D%3D%20null)%7Breturn%20true%3B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0AtelephoneCheck(%222(757)622-7382%22)%3B)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but you should test for `null` before you test `excJoin.length`. In other words, this `if(excJoin === null)` needs to appear before this `if(excJoin.length > 0)`

Comment: from W3schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

The match() method returns null if no match is found.

Comment: why not  use test instead   `const validate = phone => /regext/.test(phone);`
or its ES5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.prototype.match` (in your code: `str.match(exc)`) returns null if it didn't match the regex, so then the code is equivalent to `null.join('')`, which is an error.

Instead, check if it's null first:

```
var excResult = str.match(exc);
if (excResult === null) {
  // didn't match, do something
} else {
  // did match, do something else
}
```

Comment: perfect yeah. I understand. `join('')` was creating the error. because it had nothing to join to. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

You must test for nullity before using the object

Answer (score 1):

`str.match(exc)` returns null if there are no founds for the given pattern.
So your code should do this:

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {

  // if string contains a letter then return false
  var exc = /[a-z\?/]/;

  //The match() method retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular expression.
  var excResult= str.match(exc);

  //return false if there is a found
  if(excResult != null) {
    return false;
  }
  else{
    //there is no found cause excResult == null
    return true;
  }

telephoneCheck("2(757)622-7382");
```

Comment: I added what I thought I needed from your example and I totally looked over the fact that `join('')` couldnt join null. thanks for that. you're a legend.